# Intercept headers and body from WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient

I'm want to log headers and body from my request and response which is made trough WebClient HttpInterface in Spring 6.
For that i created a filter to log. But it is seams that the filter I can only intercept the headers not the body.

```
 final HttpAsyncClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setVersionPolicy(HttpVersionPolicy.FORCE_HTTP_1)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setConnectTimeout(this.myTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .setResponseTimeout(this.myTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(this.myTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build()
                );
        final CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = clientBuilder
                .build();

        final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(client))
                .baseUrl(this.myBaseUrl)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token)
                .filter(this.logRequest())
                .build();

        final var proxy = HttpServiceProxyFactory.builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient))
                .blockTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(this.myTimeout))
                .build();
        var myClient = proxy.createClient(MyClient.class);
```

And here my filter

```
private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest(final String id) {

        return (clientRequest, next) -> {
            return next.exchange(clientRequest).flatMap(
                    clientResponse -> {

                        final var url = String.format("[%s] %s (%s)", clientRequest.method().name(), clientRequest.url(), clientResponse.statusCode().value());

                        // Request
                        var requestHdrs = "";
                        for (final var header : clientRequest.headers().entrySet()) {
                            requestHdrs = requestHdrs + header.getKey() + "=" + (header.getValue().size() == 1 ? header.getValue().get(0) : header.getValue()) + "\n";
                        }
                        rawRequests.put(id, url + "\n" + requestHdrs + "\n");

                        // Response
                        var responseHdrs = "";
                        for (final var header : clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders().entrySet()) {
                            responseHdrs = responseHdrs + header.getKey() + "=" + (header.getValue().size() == 1 ? header.getValue().get(0) : header.getValue()) + "\n";
                        }
                        rawResponses.put(id, url + "\n" + responseHdrs + "\n" + clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class));

                        return Mono.just(clientResponse);
                    }
            );
        };
    }
```

The clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)) does not return the body and in the request I also do not know how to get the body.